# How to share data to facebook with new iOS SDK v4.23?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am working on an app where I have implemented Facebook sharing with graph API version v2.3 no. Now I want to update it to latest SDK and latest graph API version. i.e v2.9 so is there any changes in sharing API? because I have just updated SDK only and the image is not getting display i.e picture parameter.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_9_90_day_deprecations // Facebook is removing all possibilities to set those values dynamically while sharing. All the data will be taken from the Open Graph meta tags the URL that gets shared returns.

Comment: How exactly can we do that?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters